# Using PHP to auto populate a field in a form from the same page

Tags: php, forms

I am just wondering if this could be done with PHP. I have a catalog MySQL database, using joomla, when a customer goes inside an item, there is a Part Number, Description, etc.... and on the bottom there is a form so customers can submit their RFQ's. I was wondering if the part number field, could be auto populated so customer can just put in their name and phone number and dont have to worry about the part number. Please let me know if this can be done, any help would be really appreciated!

please take a look at this to see what I mean.

http://www.shoxwebdesign.com/edc2/aircraft-parts/catalog-2/details/2/91/catalog-2-edc001

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to change your form input field to include a value;

```
<input id="ff_elem6" class="ff_elem" type="text" value="" name="ff_nm_PartNumber[]">
```

to

```
<input id="ff_elem6" class="ff_elem" type="text" value="<?php echo $varFromDB; ?>" name="ff_nm_PartNumber[]">
```

or you can put this data in a hidden field like

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $varFromDB; ?>" name="ff_nm_PartNumber[]">
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response... I have tried this but it doesnt work... what could I be doing wrong? http://shoxwebdesign.com/edc2/aircraft-parts/catalog-2/details/2/91/catalog-2-edc001

Answer (score 0):

definitely...where you're making the form, add the value attribute to the text fields, with whatever value you want...

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo 'some field pulled from mysql';?>"/>
```

Comment: Just remember to escape that output first.

Comment: http://shoxwebdesign.com/edc2/aircraft-parts/catalog-2/details/2/91/catalog-2-edc001

Comment: can you post your PHP where you generate this: `<table width="100%" border="0" class="admintable adminlist mceItemTable"><tbody><tr class="row0"><td width="20%" valign="top" class="key"><label>Category</label></td><td>Mechanical</td></tr><tr class="row0"><td width="20%" valign="top" class="key"><label>Part Number</label></td><td>EDC001</td>...`? However you got EDC001 there, is just how you'd put it within the value attribute of the appropriate input

Comment: I use joomla, and this is a component that I installed in joomla

Comment: I don't use joomla, are you unable to post the PHP code? (or, for that matter, can you even edit it as we've suggested)

Comment: $this->assignRef('show_title', $show_title);
  $this->assignRef('pageclass_sfx', $pageclass_sfx);
  
  $config =& JoomdController::getConfig();
  
  $this->assignRef('config', $config);
  
  if($layout == "detail") {
  
   $item =& $this->get('Item');
   $fields =& $this->get('Fields');
   $this->assignRef('fields', $fields);
   
   $page_title = $item->title;
   
   $this->assignRef('item', $item);
   $this->assignRef('fields', $fields);